# RadRails is very slow on Windows 7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, ruby, radrails

I'm trying to use RadRails on Windows and it's works relatively smoothly.

But, when i hit F5 in my browser i have to wait ~15 secondes to refresh the page.
It's annoying because the CPU usage is around 5% and it's looks like RadRails is doing nothing, no debbuger activity, no sql connection and no server requests during the 15 seconds.

Did some one knows how to configure this IDE ?

Thanks

PS : i'm using ruby 1.8 available at http://rubyinstaller.org/

Edit : In first place i thought that was web server too. But it displays this debug : "Completed in 13ms (View: 11, DB: 2) | 200 OK [http://localhost/]" ... it doesn't looks guilty !

So, where is my request between the moment i hit F5 and the moment the web server receives and executes it ? Thanks again.

Comment: FWIW, I'm running RadRails and don't have this issue. You should ask over on their forums, though -- not sure StackOverflow can give you good tech support with this.

Comment: Radrails is an IDE. It sounds like you're having a problem with the web server. That's why you're not seeing any CPU activity from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I have definitively found my problem ...

I was using a distant database and the server my_sql had the reverse DNS activated.
With this option the connection takes approximatively 5 seconds if the hostname can't be resolved.

I have disabled this reverse DNS, the connection is now instant and my page doesn't need 5 seconds to render any more :)